# Char *strcat Implementation leading to Segmentation Fault

Tags: c, strcat

```
char *strcat(char*dest, char*src) {
    while (dest != '\0') {
        *dest++;
    }
    while (src != '\0') {
        *dest++ = *src++;
    }
    return dest;
}
```

I keep getting a segmentation fault on the line `*dest++ = *src++`. Any ideas on how to fix the problem?

Comment: You want to check if the values pointed to by `dest` and `src` are null terminators, not the pointers themselves. So, `while (*dest)` and `while (*src)`. Also consider making `src` a pointer to const, like so: `const char* src`.

Comment: In addition to the problem @szczurcio mentioned, you need to NULL-terminate the `dest` string and also save the original value of `dest` so it can be returned.

Comment: Why -1?  This may not be correct code, but the problem is clearly defined, with nicely formatted source sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has 4 problems:

- you are comparing pointers to the null character instead of comparing the character they point to. Since it will take incrementing the pointer an awful lot of times before it becomes 0, if at all, you are reading and/or writing beyond the end of the buffers, from/to invalid memory before this happens, hence the crash.
- you do not null terminate the destination string.
- you return the pointer to the end of the destination string instead of the original destination string. This might be a useful API, but you should use a different name for that.
- the `src` pointer should be declared as `const char *` to conform to the standard declaration for this function and to allow passing pointers to constant strings as sources.

Here is a corrected version:

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src) {
    char *saved = dest;
    while (*dest != '\0') {
        dest++;
    }
    while ((*dest++ = *src++) != '\0') {
        continue;
    }
    return saved;
}
```

Comment: this returns the original string passed in as dest, without src concatenated

Comment: +1. Add the 4th problem, possible buffer overflow on `dest`, as nothing checks if `dest` has enough allocated memory.

Comment: @AlexanderPogrebnyak: that's part of the API, nothing to complain about.  The caller is supposed to verify that, and also to ensure neither `dest` nor `src` are null pointers.

Comment: @DarthVeder: `strcat` is **supposed** to return its first argument. What makes you think `src` is not concatenated?

Comment: if I printf the result, i just recieve dest @chqrlie

Comment: @DarthVeder:  Can you post your code to a pastebin?  It does not make sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

`dest` and `source` will never become `'\0'` if they aren't null to begin with (or maybe after a long time to be correct, but you'll probalby run out of memory long before that).

You should use:

```
while(*dest != '\0'){
    dest++;
}
while(*src != '\0'){
   *dest++ = *src++;
}
```

to check the values underneath the pointers.

There are some other problems too:

- the resulting string is not null-terminated.
- a pointer to the end of the string is returned.

As mentioned by others: `src` should be a `const pointer` too.

This should do it:

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src)
{
    char *start_pos = dest;

    while(*dest != '\0')
        dest++;

    while(*src != '\0')
       *dest++ = *src++;

    *dest = '\0';
    return start_pos;
}
```

Minor detail: I would give this funtion some other name than the standard used `strcat()`.

Answer (score 1):

Okay: the Kernighan way:

```
char *strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char *org = dest;
    while(*dest++){;}
      // at this moment, *dest MUST be pointing to '\0'
    while(*dest++ = *src++){;}
      // at this moment, *dest MUST be pointing to '\0' agian
    return org;
}
```

Update (courtously @chqrlie):

```
char *strcat(char *dest, char *src)
{
    char *org = dest;
    for(; *dest; dest++) {;}
      // at this moment, dest MUST be pointing to '\0'
    while(*dest++ = *src++) {;}
      // at this moment, dest points past the '\0', but who cares?
    return org;
}
```

Comment: `while(*dest++ = *src++)` generates a warning if you compile with recommended cautious flags.  It is better to not play dare devil and parenthesize this kind of combined assignment/test.

Comment: -1 because you copy the source string **after** the null terminator of the destination string.  Only increment `dest` if `*dest != '\0'`

Comment: please do not brag this way when the code has a major bug in it `;-)`  C programming is a humbling experience, if you do not use `-Wall` yet, you have not spent enough time programming in C.

Comment: Commenting a bug does not remove it!  After the first loop, `dest` points **after** the `'\0'`

Comment: Which part of *After the first loop, dest points after the '\0'* do you not understand?